# SQL how to ORDER BY Statement in one column

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to order by this SQl statement to get the Item count for <%# Eval("ICount") %>

The problem is i don't know how to "ORDER BY" this one

SQL:

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY,BLG_DATE) as DDay,
      datename(month,BLG_DATE) as DMonth,
       DATEPART(YEAR,BLG_DATE) as DYear,COUNT(BLG_DATE) as ICount
FROM [BLG] 
INNER JOIN [ACC] 
ON [BLG].ACC_ID=[ACC].ACC_ID 
WHERE [BLG].ACC_ID='1'and [BLG].BLG_DATE LIKE '%2013%' ORDER BY --????
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="childRep" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <li><a href="blog.aspx?month=<%# Eval("DMonth") %>"><em><%# Eval("DDay") %></em><%# Eval("DMonth") %><span><%# Eval("ICount") %></span></a></li>  
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

I need the column DMonth,DDay,DYear, and ICount to fill the Repeater

Note: I only have table BLG(BLG_ID,ACC_ID,BLG_DATE) and ACC(ACC_ID,ACC_USER,ACC_PASS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is this one you are looking for?

```
SELECT DATEPART(DAY,BLG_DATE) as DDay,
      datename(month,BLG_DATE) as DMonth,
       DATEPART(YEAR,BLG_DATE) as DYear ,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM [BLG] 
          INNER JOIN [ACC]  ON [BLG].ACC_ID=[ACC].ACC_ID 
         WHERE [BLG].ACC_ID='1'and [BLG].BLG_DATE LIKE '%2013%') AS ICount
FROM [BLG] 
INNER JOIN [ACC] 
ON [BLG].ACC_ID=[ACC].ACC_ID 
WHERE [BLG].ACC_ID='1'and [BLG].BLG_DATE LIKE '%2013%'
```

Comment: THANK YOU. you save my life, hahaha. iv doing this for 1 hr XD

Comment: @Nithesh, sorry, but I think your query returned total count of records, not count of duplicate records.

Comment: hi @devarth. thx for the comment. But it returns the count of what exactly he is selecting. I think that is required for him.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT t.DDay, t.DMonth, t.DYear, cnt = COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT
          DDay = DATEPART(DAY, BLG_DATE) 
        , DMonth = DATENAME(MONTH, BLG_DATE) 
        , DYear = DATEPART(YEAR, BLG_DATE) 
    FROM [BLG] b
    JOIN [ACC] a ON b.ACC_ID = a.ACC_ID
    WHERE b.ACC_ID = '1'
        AND b.BLG_DATE LIKE '%2013%'
) t
GROUP BY t.DDay, t.DMonth, t.DYear
ORDER BY 
      DYear
    , DMonth
    , DDay
```